# why is this not changing dot size? (Jupyter notebooks, Pandas and Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, jupyter-notebook

i mean i have really tried to make this plot to have different dot sizes, but i'm running out of ideas, and well, i'll show a slice of data and the code:

(this is the result of my last try, it has looked better before, rn i just want to change dot size)

any Ideas?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3DQN.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfvgy.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR8Ho.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

you must provide example to get answer by yourself.

click following link : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

This time, I made a simple example.

```
import seaborn as sns   
df =  sns.load_dataset("tips")
```

df.head()

```
total_bill  tip     sex smoker  day time    size
0   16.99   1.01    Female  No  Sun Dinner  2
1   10.34   1.66    Male    No  Sun Dinner  3
2   21.01   3.50    Male    No  Sun Dinner  3
3   23.68   3.31    Male    No  Sun Dinner  2
4   24.59   3.61    Female  No  Sun Dinner  4
```

**Code**

lets make scatter plot

```
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue='sex')
```

[image]

---

if you want change size whole, use parameter `s`

```
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue='sex', s=100)
```

[image]

---

If you want to make the size of the scatter different depending on the value of a specific column, and you also want to change the size, you can put the name of the column in `size` parameter and put the range of the size in `sizes` parameter as a tuple.

```
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue='sex', 
                size='size', sizes=(10, 200))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, for both things, and yes i had to group rows so i could provide the sizes for the dots, cause actually i was taking the raw rows with thousands of different values for the size. thank you again

Comment: @rebecagodoy I'm glad if it was helpful, but I hope you will ask questions more clearly next time. It was difficult to answer because it was not clear how you wanted to change the size. And provide example by yourself, plz